# Restoring Windows 8 Backup while keeping Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, windows

I have a 32-bit Laptop with original pre-installed Windows 8. Before last month I have taken a backup with Windows OS tools and I have then installed Ubuntu 12.04.

Now I would like to install the backup-ed windows 8 OS along the side of Ubuntu. I don't how to do that and I fear losing my data while installing.

I also want to know whether we can install Windows after Ubuntu has been installed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I have edited your question to correct the spelling and grammar issues. Please [edit you question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/398039/edit) back if I accidentally changed your original meaning.

Answer (score 1):

From what you said in the question, I'll assume that you have Windows 8 completely removed and you only have Ubuntu 12.04 on your laptop.

Here is the steps that I would do, in summary, installing Windows 8 alongside Ubuntu first then restoring it from your backup

1. Install GParted (search in the software center).  Here's a screenshot of it:

   [image]

   Right click the Ubuntu partition and click "Resize/Move".  You will need at least 20 GB for Windows 8, which is 20480 MB.  Enter that in the "Free Space Following" box, or put a larger number if you need more space for Windows 8.
2. Grab a Windows 8 Installation CD and boot into it.  Enter you license key (next, next, next) and stop at this screen.

   [image]

   Choose "custom".  Then select the Free space, create a new NTFS partition, and click on "Next".
3. By now you should have Windows 8 and Ubuntu on your computer, and your computer only boots into Windows 8.  Now boot into a Ubuntu Live CD or USB, and install Boot-Repair.  Type the following lines in the terminal:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install boot-repair`

   Launch Boot Repair from the Dash, and select "Advanced"

   [image]

   Select "Reinstall GRUB".  Then apply and restart your computer after Boot Repair did its job.
4. Now you should be able to boot into both Windows 8 and Ubuntu with Windows 8 being a clean install.  Boot into Windows 8, then go to the "Windows 7 File Recovery" panel.

   [image]

   Plug in the drive where your backup is located and Restore the backup.
5. Done!